# Plotting netcdf file with raster package leads to distorted representation, R

Tags: r, maps, geospatial, spatial, r-raster

I want to properly plot this netcdf file: http://www.filedropper.com/sshgridsv16092015060412nc (Downloaded originally from [here: https://opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/merged_alt/L4/cdr_grid/contents.html](https://opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/merged_alt/L4/cdr_grid/contents.html))

But run into issues:

I should be able to just plot the raster (the SLA variable):

```
library(RNetCDF)
library(raster)
library(maptools)

d <- raster("ssh_grids_v1609_2015060412.nc.nc4", varname = "SLA")

plot(d)
#plot SLA
```

But the result is very weird as you can see with the provided file.

Especially when plotting a world map on top:

```
data(wrld_simpl)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = T)
```

They don't match at all :/

So I thought maybe the problem is with the longitude (ranging from 4.839944e-09 to 360)

Then I read that raster::rotate(d)

should be perfect for that (to get longitude to -180 to 180), but it won't let me. I get this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In .local(x, ...) :
  this does not look like an appropriate object for this function
```

and

```
plot(d)
```

still looks the same.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Netcdf file is not only "rotated" in longitude but x and y are also at the wrong position. The way it has been entered in the netcdf is not usual apparently.
I downloaded the netcdf directly on [the OpenDap server](https://opendap.jpl.nasa.gov/opendap/allData/merged_alt/L4/cdr_grid/ssh_grids_v1609_2015060412.nc.html) because your filedropper link seems to be corrupt.
Anyway, here is my proposition:

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)

d <- raster("ssh_grids_v1609_2015060412.nc.nc4", varname = "SLA")

# transpose x to y and double flip the map
m.r <- flip(flip(t(d), direction = "y"), direction = "x")

# then rotate from 0:360 to -180:180
rm.r <- rotate(m.r)

data(wrld_simpl)

plot(rm.r)
plot(wrld_simpl, add = T)
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It seems to work good, but when I click zoom plot in RStudio the world map and rm.r are off again. Is there maybe an additional problem? Cheers

Comment: You should not resize plot with raster object after they are plot. Usually, the redrawing does not work with rasters. So open an empty window the size you want with `x11()` for instance, and then plot the raster.